# Is there an easy way to clone a database, it's structure, and the last 100 records?

Tags: mysql

I need a reasonably quick way to setup a test database that mirrors production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just [make a backup](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-methods.html).

Comment: I was concerned that this would take too long, but ended up doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [mysqldump --no-data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-data)

Comment: Ah! Then can I just make the data into inserts and run it?

Comment: There's also a comment on that page about using the `--where` flag to specify a LIMIT but I've not tried it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Take [backup](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-methods.html) of production database.
2. When ever needed [restore](http://php.about.com/od/learnmysql/ss/mysql_backup_2.htm) that backup in test database.

Answer (score 0):

different vendors provide import\export APIs and tools that implement them (command-line and GUI). 
Usually export query looks something like

`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE :exportFileAbsolutePath

              USING
            (
                  DELIMITER '',''
                  Y2BASE 2000
                  REMOTESOURCE ''JDBC''
                  ESCAPECHAR ''\''
            )

            AS SELECT {1}
              FROM SCHEMA.{0}`

Which DB vendor you work with?

Sorry did not see mysql tag. see http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/360

Answer (score 0):

Cloning a schema and the associated tables and indexes are easy.  Others have suggested mysqldump.

Selecting the most recent 100 rows of each of the tables is easy if and only if there are no foreign keys.  If there are foreign keys, you'll have to develop a process to select the rows you want, and the associated rows, to maintain the referential integrity of the schema.